# X11 MIT-SHM performance of XShmPutImage

Tags: x11

I just added the option to use MIT-SHM in a big application. The reason was that the Xorg process consumed 15% cpu (more than my process).

This is for just two windows, each 960×540, 30fps (using x11 locally; Linux)

It works in that I can see that the rendering is non-tearing (for which I previously had to use X11-DBE).

But the Xorg process still uses 15% cpu.

What I expected was that using XShmPutImage lets the Xorg process suffice with near 0% cpu usage.

When I disable the call to XShmPutImage then Xorg uses near 0%. This is a clue that it is not some other interaction with X11 that is causing the 15% cpu (such as event-handling).

So XShmPutImage is causing lots of work in Xorg. Can this be reduced? Can MIT-SHM be combined with X11-DBE and would that help?